# nginx rewrite specific subdomain to nonssl

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a 301 redirect that writes all subdomains to https. now the client would like to have a http only subdomain. how should i catch this request in the https server and redirect it to http?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name *.example.com;

    # need to catch specific subdomain here and redirect it to http permanent.
    # i know this is wrong, but it illustrates what i must do
    if($host == 'subdomain.example.com'){
        return 301 http://subdomain.example.com$request_uri?$query_string;
    }

    # else continue redirect as normal
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define multiple `server` blocks.  See [this page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for the `server_name` precedence.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    # ... what you want to serve at http://subdomain.example.com/ ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri?$query_string;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    # ... what you want to serve at https://example.com/ ...
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    return 301 http://subdomain.example.com$request_uri?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: the ssl certificate isn't a wildcard certificate, so this configuration will fail right?

Comment: Of course you need to prepare a proper certificate for each ssl enabled `server` blocks.  If you think it's unnecessary to handle accesses to `https://subdomain.example.com`, just remove that `server` block, but you cannot prevent users from accidentally or intentionally opening that URL.

Comment: @r3wt because if there's only one ssl server block - it's the implicit default.